# How to visualize a continuous variable across time while distinguishing between different conditions?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am working with a dataset that includes a continuous variable (let's call it z) and two categorical variables (x and y) representing different conditions. I want to create a single graph that allows me to visualize how z changes over time while also highlighting the differences based on the conditions of x and y.
Specifically, I want the graph to show:

- Evolution of z over time.
- Differentiation between entries where x is A and where x is not A.
- Differentiation between entries where y is a and where y is not a.
  Can someone guide me on how to achieve this using a common data visualization tool like ggplot?

  library(dynamite)

  data(categorical_example)

This is not my real dataset. Also, I did something like [this](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/vis_interaction_effects/) but it just adds two lines for x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential solution is:

```r
# install.packages("dynamite")
library(dynamite)
library(tidyverse)

data(categorical_example)

categorical_example %>%
  mutate(is_x_A = ifelse(x == "A", "x is A", "x is not A"),
         is_y_a = ifelse(y == "a", "y is a", "y is not a")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = z, color = interaction(is_x_A, is_y_a, sep = " & "))) +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_color_hue(name = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-27 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Or perhaps:

```r
# install.packages("dynamite")
library(dynamite)
library(tidyverse)

data(categorical_example)

categorical_example %>%
  mutate(is_x_A = ifelse(x == "A", "x is A", "x is not A"),
         is_y_a = ifelse(y == "a", "y is a", "y is not a")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = z, color = is_x_A)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_color_hue(name = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~is_y_a)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-27 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I think the 'best' solution depends on your actual data; do either of these approaches solve your problem?

Comment: That sounds like a different problem @ebrahimi. I'm not sure what might be causing that, so the best thing would probably be to post another question and see if someone can work out a solution